# How to get the colour of a Windows title bar text in .NET

Tags: .net, windows, vb.net, windows-10

I have 2 versions of a custom icon for my application.

One is half black and the other is half white.

I want to use a different one for the apps title bars depending on the darkness of the users "Accent Colour" in Windows 10.

I can get the colour in ABGR format by checking the "AccentColor" registry value at "Software\Microsoft\Windows\DWM" and with a bit of bit-shifting I can get it into RGB.

I was going to write a function that calculated the brightness/darkness of this value and choose the correct icon based on this but I noticed that when I was changing my Accent Colour and debugging the app the text in the title bar would be either black or white depending on the Accent Colour. It was doing the same kind of thing I want to do for my icons, so I thought that if I could read that title bar text colour value from *somewhere* that would save me writing a function.

Is there a way to get at this value in a vb.net application?

Comment: I haven't checked specifically but I would think that the `SystemColors` type would have a member to provide that value.

Comment: Good question. I wondered about system colors too, put a pInvoke to GetSystemColors and this in a form load; `For i = 1 To 24` `TextBox1.AppendText(i & "-" & GetSysColor(i).ToString("X8") & Environment.NewLine)` `Next i` - bummer of it is, if you run the app, copy the values, change the accent so everything flips, and run the app again then nothing has changed in the colors read.. So it looks like that bit of theming is done outside of this particular color set

Comment: I'd say, given that it looks like youre 99% the way there anyway with the registry route, should just proceed with using that while this question is open..

Comment: Yeah, looks like I won't be getting an answer. So what I've gone with for now is simply checking the registry key for "ColorPrevalence" in DWM and if this is 0 then the user isn't applying "Accent Color" to title bars so I just go with my black logo (title bars should be white). However, if this is a 1 then I get the ABRG from the "AccentColor" key and split it into three integer variables for r, g, and b, then I use this little calculation to determine if it is "light" or "dark" and set the correct icon for my windows - `Dim isDarkAccent As Boolean = ((5 * g) + (2 * r) + b) <= 1024`